# Music app without iTunes

Tags: iphone, music, dropbox

I don't always have PC with me. Also, I have quite big music collection on my DropBox. Is there any good app for iPhone that I can use to download music from DropBox and listen to without connecting to iTunes?

Answer (score 7):

I managed to find appropriate app for this purpose. Its name is VLC for iOS -> https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/vlc-for-ios/id650377962?mt=8

I can connect my DropBox account and play music.